# Mercurial HG_NODE hook variable on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial-hook

I'm currently testing mercurial hooks on windows and it seems like I cannot access hook variables....

here's hgrc content :

> [hooks] 
> prechangegroup = ruby prechangegroup.rb test1 test2 $HG_NODE

I also tried with %HG_NODE%

Here's prechangegroup.rb content

> ARGV.each do|a| 
>       puts "Argument: #{a}" 
>   end

It prints out:

> Argument: test1
>   Argument: test2
>   Argument: $HG_NODE$

Followed by the normal push output...

Any idea? (probably something stupid but, I can't seem to find it)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a good documentation right on mercurial's website.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks

I tried with a variable other than %HG_NODE% like %HG_URL% and the variable worked.
So it probably means that the variable is inaccessible from that hook.

Answer (score 2):

`HG_NODE` is an environmental variable. You don't have to use it as arguments on the command line. Instead, you should be able to use it as `puts ENV['HG_NODE']` (found through search engine as I'm not a ruby guy)

Comment: +1 for this one, but the real problem was that the variable was inaccessible from that hook. Thanks though!